# ATI driver and boot problem “Starting Timidity alsa midi emulation”

Tags: boot, fglrx

After upgrade, I can no longer boot into gui. It stops on "Starting Timidity alsa midi emulation", but it's possible this has nothing to do with alsa. Could it just be that my boot is messed up somehow??

I also tried removing and reinstalling fglrx, but no changes.

I've been to many forum questions already but no one seems to have solved this.

```
http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1871360.html
http://askubuntu.com/questions/120430/ubuntu-fails-on-boot-up
```

This is really frustrating. All my mind is on that computer.. :(

My specs: ElementaryOS, Dell Studio 1550

Comment: Nevermind ... somehow solved this by uninstalling fglrx again. First time it didn't work...

Comment: askubuntu for elemtaryOS, your are fun :)

Comment: What? There's no difference especially in the context of ATI drivers or "Timidity" (whatever that is)...elementary = ubuntu! Next time I'll just lie to them and say I have the general 'ubuntu' version and they will just go along and help me with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the issue has been resolved let me add this: It had nothing to do with timidity. It just had some problem with ati driver. When I tried removing fglrx (apt-get remove in recovery mode), it first didn't work, after two attempts it somehow got resolved. Looks like the best drivers are native.

Comment: With "native driver", do you mean the Ubuntu open source driver, or the ATI driver? Since I have the same problem as yours, but I haven't got fglrx installed. I had previously though.

Comment: I mean non-proprietary driver. The one that you get out of the box.